# adding class with jquery doesn't work as intended for dashboard icon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this jquery code to `addClass('text-info')` whenever `.dashboard__icon--small.fa.fa-circle` `hasClass('text-info')`. And the wanted output is so that only `book2` circle becomes blue not `book1` because `first_edit` of `book1` doesnt have the circle in blue like `first_edit` of `book2` has. I looked at `closest()` function of jquery but didn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.dashboard__icon--small.fa.fa-circle').hasClass('text-info')) {
       $('.dashboard__icon.fa.fa-circle').addClass('text-info');
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<table class="form-table form-table--big">
  <tbody class="form-table__body">
    <tr class="form-table__row">
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_object_ids[]" id="checkbox_object_ids_" value="">
        <a aria-hidden="true" class="dashboard__tool fa fa-tasks js-toggle" data-href="" href="#" title="Show"></a>
        <i aria-hidden="true" aria-title="Processed" class="dashboard__icon fa fa-circle"></i>
      </td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <a class="js-toggle" href="#">book1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row--extra hidden" data-toggle="">
      <td class="form-table__data"></td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <div class="form-table__meta-row">
          <a class="js-toggle" data-href="" href="#">first_edit</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row--extra hidden" data-toggle="">
      <td class="form-table__data"></td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <div class="form-table__meta-row">
          <a class="js-toggle" data-href="" href="#">second_edit</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row">
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_object_ids[]" id="checkbox_object_ids_" value="">
        <a aria-hidden="true" class="dashboard__tool fa fa-tasks js-toggle" data-href="" href="#" title="Show"></a>
        <i aria-hidden="true" aria-title="Processed" class="dashboard__icon fa fa-circle"></i>
      </td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <a class="js-toggle" href="#">Book2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row--extra hidden" data-toggle="">
      <td class="form-table__data"></td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <div class="form-table__meta-row">
          <a class="js-toggle" data-href="" href="#">first_edit</a>
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="dashboard__icon dashboard__icon--small fa fa-circle text-info" title="New"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Wanted output:

[image: wanted output]

Comment: Just looking at the jQuery code, the logic seems off; in plain English, it's saying, "if this span has this class, add that same class to the span"... which would result in nothing happening.

Comment: okay if I remove the span, they are 2 different classes

Comment: Well, that's the other problem :). You are lacking an initial `.` in front of the first class, so it's looking for an element like `<dashboard__icon class="dashboard__icon--small fa fa-circle">`. Just add a dot after the opening quote.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh okay yes that's a mistake. That works now. But my main problem is how to not color with blue the seconds book circle, because `first_edit` of `second book` does not have the `class="dashboard__icon--small fa fa-circle`.

Comment: I... have no idea what you're talking about (because there's no CSS in the code). But I would say that if you need to identify specific types of elements, you should use an additional CSS class (if there is more than one) or ID (if there is only ever one in the document).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I cant put an ID because there is not only ever one and could you explain what do you mean with additional CSS class? I edited my question and added an image what the wanted output is.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at, adding the links to the CSS and the picture helped. Basically, you don't want an `if`. You want an `each`. You want to go through all of the elements that have the `text-info` class and add the class to an associated element. The problem here is the way the HTML is structured; a table is not a great structure of hierarchical data like this. If you can't change the HTML, it's going to be a bit more challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what went wrong. When the page loaded, an `if` block is run with the condition

```
$('.dashboard__icon--small.fa.fa-circle').hasClass('text-info')
```

[`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), when called on a jQuery object that matches many elements, will return true if any of the elements have the class (or classes) given in its argument. So that means this will go into the `if` block if there's any circle that has "text-info".

In the `if` block, the following code is run:

```
$('.dashboard__icon.fa.fa-circle').addClass('text-info');
```

Now, this will add the "text-info" class to all elements that match that selector, irrespective of where they exist relative to the element(s) matched in the `if` block. To link the two things together (the elements matched in the condition and and elements matched in the block), we need to get a bit more complex.

Here's one way of doing what you need. I've added comments to each line of code to explain what it's doing. Hopefully that makes sense. I've created many variables so that it was easier to explain, and then included a way to do everything in one line in case that matters.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // step 1: get all of the small icons that have the text-info class
    $('.dashboard__icon--small.fa.fa-circle.text-info').each(function (index, el) {
      // for each of those,
      // get the closest table row
      var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
      // get all of the previous rows that have the form-table__row class
      var bookRows = tr.prevAll('.form-table__row');
      // get the first one (should be the one closest to the tr of the text-info 
      var myBookRow = bookRows.first();
      // find the circle icon for this row
      var myBookRowCircle = myBookRow.find('.dashboard__icon.fa.fa-circle');
      // add the text-info class
      myBookRowCircle.addClass('text-info');
      // all in one line
      $(el).closest('tr').prevAll('.form-table__row').first().find('.dashboard__icon.fa.fa-circle').addClass('text-info');
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<table class="form-table form-table--big">
  <tbody class="form-table__body">
    <tr class="form-table__row">
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_object_ids[]" id="checkbox_object_ids_" value="">
        <a aria-hidden="true" class="dashboard__tool fa fa-tasks js-toggle" data-href="" href="#" title="Show"></a>
        <i aria-hidden="true" aria-title="Processed" class="dashboard__icon fa fa-circle"></i>
      </td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <a class="js-toggle" href="#">book1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row--extra hidden active" data-toggle="">
      <td class="form-table__data"></td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <div class="form-table__meta-row">
          <a class="js-toggle" data-href="" href="#">first_edit</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row--extra hidden active" data-toggle="">
      <td class="form-table__data"></td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <div class="form-table__meta-row">
          <a class="js-toggle" data-href="" href="#">second_edit</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row">
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_object_ids[]" id="checkbox_object_ids_" value="">
        <a aria-hidden="true" class="dashboard__tool fa fa-tasks js-toggle" data-href="" href="#" title="Show"></a>
        <i aria-hidden="true" aria-title="Processed" class="dashboard__icon fa fa-circle"></i>
      </td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <a class="js-toggle" href="#">Book2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-table__row--extra hidden active" data-toggle="">
      <td class="form-table__data"></td>
      <td class="form-table__data">
        <div class="form-table__meta-row">
          <a class="js-toggle" data-href="" href="#">first_edit</a>
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="dashboard__icon dashboard__icon--small fa fa-circle text-info" title="New"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, for all the explanations. I appreciate it a lot. :)

Comment: Just one more question. I wanted to add this line too inside the function `$(el).closest('tr').prevAll('.form-table__row').first().find('tr.form-table__row--extra').addClass('active');` , but I don't get this added, can you tell me why it won't work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As you can see, that line is already in the function.

Comment: nvm, I made it work like this: `$(el).closest('tr').prevAll('.form-table__row').first().find('.dashboard__tool.fa.fa-tasks.js-toggle').click();` . Thank you so much one more time. I appreciate your help a lot.